# Why Sqlite db is not located in /data/data/{package name}/databases but in /data/user/0?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I created sqlite in my android device.
many people said that the location of sqlite is in /data/data/{package name}/databases.
but not my case...
the log is below
D/TAG: /data/user/0/com.jakchang.savelocation/databases/memo

and I can't find any directory about  /data/user/0/ there is no user in data.
how can I fix the path?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I fix the path?

use the Context's **getDatabasePath** method.

They are effectively the same place one is an alias of the other. You should also not really need to know as you should utilise the Context's **getDatabasePath** method to ascertain the path to the database rather than hard coding the path.

e.g. (this from the one device) :-

[image]

and :-

[image]